# Postgres: How do I extract year and month from a date?

Tags: sql, postgresql

One of my columns is a date type in the following format: YYYY-MM-DD. I want to extract YYYY-MM. So far, the resources I've come across show me that I can extract either year using `SELECT extract(year from order_date)...` but I can't figure out how to extract both the year and the month. I tried the following but it didn't work: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_extract.asp

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just want to point out that it is often convenient to leave the value as a *date*.  If so, use `date_trunc()`:

```
select date_trunc('month', order_date) as yyyymm
```

If you really want a string, you should accept Nick's answer.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff would you upvote my question? Apparently, I am not allowed to ask any for questions for the time being. The hep section says that it may be due to previously asking unhelpful questions. Can you give me an upvote so I can keep participating here?

Answer (score 4):

In PostgreSQL you can use [`TO_CHAR()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html):

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(order_date, 'YYYY-MM')
```

Output (if `order_date = '2020-04-06'`):

```
2020-04
```

Note if your column is not already a `date` or `timestamp` you will need to cast it to a `date` or `timestamp` (e.g. `order_date::date`).

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=e9648366aab953b0eca993d5e954c80b)

Comment: That is so much better than my solution!